# push element of array to object as value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change an array to object like this :

```
array = ["blue" , "txt2" , "red" ,"txt4" , "txt5" , "txt6" ,"txt7" , "txt8" , "txt9" ]
   
pages = {"page1" :["blue","txt2", "red"] , "page2" : ["txt4", "txt5", "txt6"], "page3" : ["txt7" ,"txt8", "txt9"]
```

Every key in `pages` object should have an array value with 3 elements of array (the last key can have less) , so for example if an array have 110 elements we will have 37 `pages` (page1 , page 2 , ... , page37) and page37 will have 1 elements.

So I want put every 3 elements in array as value of a key in the `pages` object

But I don't know how to do it.. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a reason for creating an object with incremental keys? Why not create an array of arrays?

Comment: @adiga It might be so the code can directly display the keys as page numbers on the HTML page, although indeed displaying "Go to page1" is strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by iterating over `array` and extract `3` items from `array` on every iteration by using `splice` method, like this:

```js
let array = ["blue" , "txt2" , "red" ,"txt4" , "txt5" , "txt6" ,"txt7" , "txt8" , "txt9", "text10" ]
let pages= {}, i= 1;
while(array.length > 0){
    pages[`page${i++}`] = array.splice(0,3)
}

console.log(pages)
```

with this manner, you loose the original values in the `array`, if you want to keep items in the `array` untuched, you can make copy of your original data like `let copiedArray = [...array]` and then call splice method on the `copiedArray` and also check the `length` of `copiedArray` in the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Get every third index and add all the elements from that point to that point plus three (if that index is near the end it won't error; it will just add the remaining elements):

```js
const initial = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

let paginated = {};
let counter = 0

while (counter < initial.length) {
 paginated['page' + parseInt(counter / 3 + 1)] = initial.slice(counter, counter + 3);
 counter += 3;
}
 
console.log(paginated);
```

Comment: Just a small remark. It's a bit weird to have a while loop when you define a counter and use this counter as a condition to end the loop. This feels like an ideal job for a simple for loop :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir Indeed, and I knew that. I was just used to using while-loops in Python for incrementing counters up to a certain point ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a more configurable solution you might look to a `chunk` utility function for the initial division of the input array, and then map that as desired to your result object (here using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and mapping over the resulting chunked array to assign 'page' keys based on index).

```js
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    result.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }

  return result;
}

const array = ['blue', 'txt2', 'red', 'txt4', 'txt5', 'txt6', 'txt7', 'txt8', 'txt9'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    chunk(array, 3).map((chunk, index) => [`page${index + 1}`, chunk])
);

console.log(result);
```

see: [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) for discussion.